# Cropping a large geotiff in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, clip, compression

I have a DEM of Saint Lucia, obtained from the [CHARIM database](http://www.charim-geonode.net/layers/geonode:dem). It is a large geotiff (150MB), and I would like to crop it as I only need a small part of it. I have been trying to use `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper` in QGIS, but it fails because it says I need thousands of TB of disk space to complete the operation. From reading around, I presume that this is because the file is already compressed, however I don't really know how to go about solving it.

This is the layer metadata:

```
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
/Users/cameron/Desktop/Design IV/St Lucia GIS/topography.tiff
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=779.13000488281
STATISTICS_MEAN=nan
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-inf
STATISTICS_STDDEV=nan
Dimensions
X: 4536 Y: 8763 Bands: 1
Origin
-61.0813,14.1115
Pixel Size
4.61889e-05,-4.61889e-05
No Data Value
-1e+38 
Data Type
Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
-61.0812601912316993,13.7067470580471564 : -60.8717473436720837,14.1115003832598784
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing instead? I am relatively new to GIS and this is the first thing I have come across that I can't immediately find my way around.

EDIT: The Clipper settings are as follows:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 507118.619912 1549423.97735 511757.851837 1546542.77015 -of GTiff
```

And the error log:

```
Warning 1: Computed -srcwin 1.09806e+10 -3.35451e+10 1.0044e+08 6.23788e+07 falls completely outside raster extent. Going on however.
ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 8291942400 bytes, whereas 25061401106245716 are at least necessary.`
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post a `Clipper` settings you used?

Comment: The first thing I would do is assign a projected CRS rather than a geographic one. I'm not familiar with the area so I can't recommend a proper CRS but with some digging around you should be able to find the right one to use.

Comment: I have the same problem currently and the same error. I tried re-projecting the raster, but this didnt help to solve it. Any other ideas? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZhW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZhW.png)

Comment: I solved it by using qgis tool "clip raster by polygon".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147104)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in your **input extent**, you defining extent from other CRS so the `Clipper` trying clip the:

`-61.0812601912316993,13.7067470580471564 : 60.8717473436720837,14.1115003832598784`

to

`507118.619912,1549423.97735 : 511757.851837,1546542.77015`

Which makes raster much bigger ("thousands of TB") than base raster 150MB

You have to reproject your input raster to CRS you are using, or in clipper extent use `EPSG:4326 (+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs)` coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

```
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
-61.0812601912316993,13.7067470580471564 : -60.8717473436720837,14.1115003832598784
```

Your raster is in longitude-latitude coordinates, but you are trying to clip it using UTM coordinates, so you're actually creating a much larger raster, rather than cropping it into something smaller. You have two choices: use lat-long coordinates in the clipper, or reproject the raster to the utm coordinate system of your choice using the Warp(Reproject) tool under the raster menu.